# Only pulling one item out of a django manytomany

Tags: python, django, django-models

This should pull one record out of the model shown at the bottom to pass to javascript to display on the **UI**.
I'm having issues pulling the `location` manytomany data to push across. this is  because it only pulls one item and not all the items associated in the many to many.
`location` is used to place the tags on a `select2 multiselect`
the `skillset` data is not required currently

```
def GetPersonnelData(request, res_id):

    data = []

    res = Resource.objects.get(id=res_id)
    if not res: return HttpResponseNotFound()

    role = list(Role.objects.values_list('role_name').filter(id=res.role_id))
    emp = list(Employer.objects.values_list('employer_name').filter(id=res.employer_id))
    teamz = list(Team.objects.values_list('team_name').filter(id=res.teams_id))

    t = {
            "title":res.title,
            "pk":res.pk,
            "last_name":res.last_name,
            "preferred_name":res.preferred_name,
            "employstatus":res.employstatus,
            "employer":emp,
            "business_phone":res.business_phone, 
            "mobile_phone":res.mobile_phone,
            "email":res.email,
            "teams":teamz,
            "role_name":role,
            "notes":res.notes,
            "updated_by":res.updated_by,
            "updated_on":res.updated_on,
        }

    data.append(t);
    print data

    loc = Resource.objects.get(pk=res_id)
    for x in loc.location.all().filter(resource=res_id):
        l = {
            "location":x.name,
            }
    print x
```

Django Model

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    employer = models.ForeignKey('Employer')
    employstatus = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    role = models.ForeignKey('Role')
    teams = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    location = models.ManyToManyField('Location')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    business_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    skillset = models.ManyToManyField('ReferenceSkillList')
```

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with skillset here at all.

Comment: That's because I don't need it here. Its used elsewhere in the app so no point pulling it if its not needed. Did you read the question?

Comment: so nothing actually useful to add then @Moe Far

Comment: It's a culture in stackoverflow, and it's necessary for indexing @SpeedyH30

Comment: To just change something that was actually correct but not actually help with the issue I was questioning. That's the problem with the culture. I wonder why a lot of people don't want to learn programming with some of the comments you get on here. As well as the lack of help you actually get from so called knowledgeable people. if its not an easy answer people don't really care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `print x` to print all the locations you should change the indentation to be within the for block (it's outside it now, you should be getting a unknown name error). Like so:

```
for x in loc.location.all().filter(resource=res_id):
    l = {
        "location":x.name,
        }
    print x
```

If you want to gather all the location names into the dict l you should change it to this:

```
l = {"location":[]}
for x in loc.location.all().filter(resource=res_id):
    l["location"] += x.name
```

Before you were creating a new dict on every iteration of the loop only keeping the result of the last instantiation.

Comment: yea I don't want to print it I think Doru has deleted some code when he edited it. Joy, Idealy I want the locations names in data

Comment: because currently your code gives me this `location: ["w", "o", "r", "k", "h", "o", "m", "e"]`

Comment: My bad, try `l["location"].append(x.name)` instead

Comment: That said @Rolf, I changed it about a bit,
so I added it to your answer